# About an JPQL exception:__key__ filter value must be a Key

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jpql

select user from User user,Book book where user.idKey = book.userid

This is a JPQL query. "user.idKey" and "book.userid" both are type of Key.

But I get this excption:
**key** filter value must be a Key

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a join. Joins aren't supported by the App Engine datastore.